# Stack Overflow is its own country

Tags: discussion, fun

Just [found this](http://the9988.deviantart.com/art/Map-of-the-Internet-1-0-427143215) via [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/this-beautiful-map-of-the-internet-is-insanely-detailed-1512236854/@jcondliffe).

Stack Overflow <strike>is on an island</strike> next to About.com, Ask.com and Quora. It is northeast of Google <strike>and near the sea of Ask</strike>. Got to love the capital name.

[image]

(Click to enlarge)

Comment: Seems like the Programmer Ocean (south east, east of Apple and south of Linux) would've been a better location.

Comment: also... seems that [this](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/015/b/c/map_of_the_internet_1_0__by_the9988-d72b5tb.jpg) is the original link. Bigger resolution

Comment: Should it not be bigger? Much bigger?

Comment: I'm glad they kept the orange color.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Thank you! I had to copy into a photo editor and zoom in to see with the first link

Comment: Hahahaha, Facebook has a provincial capital named "Candy Crush Saga" and a "Duckface peninsula"

Comment: And the Capitol has a "Surveillance Center"

Comment: Stack overflow is the main contributor to the Programmers world. It should be bigger than Facebook and Twitter in terms of knowledge

Comment: @HemantBarhate Is this the programmers world or the whole internet?

Comment: Is there already a Discourse colony? And if so, shouldn't the capital be of Stack Overflow be renamed? :-)

Comment: I kinda feel Atwood-Spolsky is just the *administrative* capital, a bit like Washington (No offense, Jeff and Joel). Meta is New York City - not the official capital, but the powerhouse of the place, big, dirty, and gritty. If you make it there, you can make it anywhere (on the network)

Comment: Love the Grand Torrent, it's just a current that flows from sharing site to sharing site

Comment: Well, at least he's realistic... he includes porn sites as well. Many of them.

Comment: @Pëkka: Great, now I wish there would be Meta/Stack Exchange fanfiction! "When I first came to Stack Overflow I was young and naive, I wished to gain reputation fast and wanted to become famous for my solutions to unsolvable problems. But time changes all that...the more time I spent in Stack Overflow the more time I had to spent in Meta. Meta is one of these places that chew you through and spit you back into the trashcan you came from. Ones somebody said to me 'If you can make it on Meta, you can make it anywhere on the network', these words are still ringing in my ears..."

Comment: @Time loooooool

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - actually, I am waiting for a picture with SE staff member faces on the MLP main chars.... Can only dream.... Twilight Sparkle with Jeff hairs. We had the AVGN pony.... I want to see SE versions.

Comment: Predecessors: http://xkcd.com/256/ http://xkcd.com/802/

Comment: I also like how Google invaded Apple with Android...

Answer (score 12):

I feel greatly offended by this map. *where is meta?* You would think that they could at least grace us with  Stack Overflow being the shape of a pony, and then Meta is the horn that magically weaponizes the pony that is Stack Overflow. As the #59 site in the world, I say we create our *own* map of all of the Stack Exchange sites, with ponies, unicorns, rainbows, boats, and last but not least, free-hand circles! The countries on these maps seem too ... organized. I think that they would be so much better if we made them all out of red freehand circles.

Also, I feel that one thing is missing on this map. Where can we get info about sex changes? I feel like a site of the hyphen site's former stature at least deserves a mention -- and a banner saying `Conquered by Stack Overflow in the Battle of the Hyphen-Pony in 2008`

Comment: Near tumblr, on the north-west side of the map, here lies My Little Pony island. I say: let's conquest that!

Comment: The Battle of the Hyphen was black (html-)page in history. A true Master of SEO was trampled by a horde that favored content over form. When everybody knew that the web was supposed to be full of meaningless drivel, not useful information!

Comment: @SPArchaeologist At least Tony the Pony is on our side!

Comment: I, for one, am not comfortable with Quora's troops just accoss the border

Comment: @RichardTingle I am searching where is ExpertExchange :P

Comment: Maybe we should air our grievances with the creator? I have a DA account but I haven't logged on in years.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: But conquering "My little Pony" would require us to either go through "Facebook", "Pinterest" and "MySpace" on the land way, or go by sea through the "Gossip Stream"...we are brave, but are we *that* brave?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Problem is, MLP island should have been draw in a lake INSIDE StackOverflow country.

Comment: Also, Anime island is missing One Piece. I have to share some words with the author.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: We can also go south, but that's a journey 1/3 of the times against the currents. But if we make it into the "Far Southern Datastream" at the passage at "Broadband" we can ride streams and torrents for the rest of the journey around the southern continent. Except that we'd come close certain lands where...well, we should definitely plan a long break there!

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Google->Bing->Twitter->Tumblr and here ye are. Not much better than crossing Facebook, but still to consider.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: I somehow thing there's only one quote appropriate to all that: "But I don't want to go among mad people," Alice remarked. "Oh, you can't help that," said the Cat: "we're all mad here."

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - Which Alice? The somehow mad girl with the skull ribbon and the knife or the lame Disney one? Quote for quote: "When the remarkable becomes bizarre, reason turns rancid".

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Neither - the Alice who talks with Bob, while Eve is secretly listening.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: That's a quote from the original/Lewis Carroll one...I think his Alice is actually closer to that of American McGee then it to that one of Disney.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby [FOUND!](http://blog.liquidmercurysolutions.com/Portals/156196/images/SP%20Unicorn.png) while searching for info about SP certifications. Shall we create the full squad?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: You mean recreating all sites as Unicorn-Logos? That sounds kinda awesome.

Comment: yep. That could be the post that will kill the current meta question score record.